# last change time of powerpoint document

Tags: sdk, powerpoint

Is it possible to get "last change" time of PowerPoint presentation during the editing session? I mean the time of last update of a document that already has been opened in PowerPoint (not saved file).

Answer (score 0):

Not as such.

But if you store the Total Editing Time property when the presentation is first opened, the current Total Editing Time - stored time would tell you how long the presentation's been open.

I don't think there's any way to tell the time since last change, though.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Our plugin creates video and interactive slideshows from PP presentation slides. We have to take and recompress slides from current PP presentation. This action demands quite long time for execution. So we have to know has current PP presentation been changed since last slides request to avoid waste of user time

Comment: One thought:  what if you save a copy of the presentation at the time you last converted it, then before the next conversion, use PPT's presentation compare feature (IF it's exposed through the object model ... it doesn't seem to be in 2010, which is all I have handy at the moment) to locate slides that have changed.  Kind of a wild guess on my part, but perhaps it'll help.